# Как собрать в Service 2-е переменные, которые туда передал по очереди

Tags: android, java

У меня есть ресивер, слушает смс, при поступлении смс с определённой меткой в тексте, обрабатывает его, извлекает тело и передает в сервис. Дело в том, что может возникнуть случай, когда смс придет одна за одной в течении 1 секунды, сервис сначала запустится один раз выполнится метод `onCreate()`, затем метод `onStartCommand`. Я засекал выполнение метода `onStartCommand` в моей программе занимает около 15 секунд (идет отправка на емайла этой самой переменной). Возникает еще одно смс и по анологии запускается onStartCommand и опять отправка на емайл.Я хотел узнать можно ли в сервисе эти две переменные, которые появляются с интервалом 1-2 сек. собрать в массив или одну переменную и ее отправить, а не отправлять по одной, они нужны в паре. Сервис вынесен в отдельный поток. По логам смотрю, эти две переменные там одновременно существуют, и сервис их не путает и не перезаписывает. Пробовал инициализировать массив в методе `onCreate()`, но с метода `onStartCommand` он не виден. Подскажите как быть.
Вот сервис если нужен

```
 public class MyService extends Service {

final String LOG_TAG = "myLogs";

public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onCreate");
}

public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    String str = intent.getStringExtra("telo");
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onStartCommand - element poluchen");
    someTask(str);  
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}

public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onDestroy");
}

public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onBind");
    return null;
}

void someTask(final String s) {

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "peredan v someTask ");
            for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "i = " + i + " "+s);
                try {
                    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            stopSelf();
        }
    }).start();

}
```

}

Comment: Примерно по такой же схеме, что предложил @KoVadim реализовал нотификашки о входящих сообщениях - ресивер ловит сообщение, кладёт его в базу и запускает поток, который первые несколько секунд своей жизни спит. Когда поток просыпается, он достаёт из базы все сообщения, что ресивер успел туда положить и в зависимости от кол-ва выдаёт определённую нотификашку. Ну и проверка в ресивере перед запуском потока на его выполнение - что б не запустить по потоку на каждое сообщение

Comment: Спасибо, буду через SQLite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

эти две переменные обрабатываются по очереди. Поэтому, их и не путают. Самый простой вариант, как я бы делал. Пришла смс - распарсил, записал в базу, отправил сам себе отложенный intent об этом с задержкой в несколько секунд/десятков секунд.

Когда приходит вторая смс - проверяем, что в базе есть запись о первой. Если да - извлекаем ее, отправляем почту. Если в базе ничего - нет - это "первая смс":)

А отложенный intent нужен для следующей ситуации. Вторая смс может и не прийти. А почту нужно отправить. 10-15 секунд задержки сильно погоды не испортят.